# Maclaurin Series for $\tan x$ using $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Now I know the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. Without expanding the series, how can one use the general expression for the two Macluarin series to come up with one for $\tan x$. Dividing the two sequences, doesn't seem to work out for some reason.

Comment: What goes wrong with dividing the sequences?

Comment: It ends up with no factorial signs for the sequence and simply a 1/(2n+ 1)

Comment: It sounds like you're dividing respect terms, not dividing the series. These are different things, just like they are for rational expressions.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new at this :/. So wait to be clear, if sin and cos x are represented by certain polynomial expansions, calling the sequence that gives the coefficient $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively. Would it not be correct to represent the division as  ${a_n \over b_n}$. Also how would one discern to which power (in terms of n) x will be raised to in the final polynomial given for tan x?

Comment: Alright I understood now. Since the polynomial expansions for both $cos x$ and $sin x$ have $x$ to different powers, their indices must be shifted to enable the division, correct?